# How to append number to array name in perl

Tags: perl

I have several arrays with different names. The following are my array names.

```
@node_level1_1_1=read_array_level2(@node_level1_1);
@node_level1_2_1=read_array_level2(@node_level1_2);
...
@node_level1_11_1=read_array_level2(@node_level1_11);
```

I want to parse the array starting from @node_level1_1_1 to @node_level1_11_1 another  subroutine function.I tried writing this code it didn't work out.

```
for ($j=1; $j < 12; $j++) {

  my $var= output_data_xml_nodes(4,@node_level1_$j_1);

}
```

It throws the following error when I run the code:

> Scalar found where operator expected at ./html_parser1.pl line 153,
>   near "@node_level1_$j_1"  (Missing operator before $j_1?) syntax error
>   at ./html_parser1.pl line 153, near "@node_level1_$j_1" Execution of
>   ./html_parser1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Is there any increment the array's. Kindly let me know.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: First of all: **use better variable names**. Secondly, what does `read_array_level2()` do?

Comment: Because ... you seem to be trying to modify a variable name with the contents of another variable. `@node_level1_$j_1` ? You can't do that. Which is why it's telling you it's a syntax error.

Comment: [rereads the question] Oh...oh god, no. Scrap what you're doing and use a better data structure. A hash of array references comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use more complex data structures. While creating variable names is possible (with `no strict 'refs'; @{construct string here}`) it is evil, wrong, unmaintainable etc. And it only works with global variables *shudder*

What your code example should look like:

```
my @new_node;
$new_node[1][1][1]  = read_array_level2($old_node[1][1]);
$new_node[1][2][1]  = read_array_level2($old_node[1][2]);
...;
$new_node[1][11][1] = read_array_level2($old_node[1][11]);
```

or better, use the loop

```
my @new_node;
for my $i (1 .. 12) {
    $new_node[1][$i][1] = read_array_level2($old_node[1][$i])
}
```

However, you will be dealing with array references, not arrays, most of the time. Read and re-read

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html

and friends.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use hashes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array_1 = (1, 11);
my @array_2 = (2, 22);
my %arrays  = ( 
  array_1 => [ @array_1],
  array_2 => [ @array_2]
);

for my $i (1, 2) {
  print join(",", @{$arrays{"array_$i"}}), "\n";
}
```

Another way is to use eval:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array_1 = (1, 11);
my @array_2 = (2, 22);

for my $i (1, 2) {
  my $array_ref = eval('\@'."array_$i");
  print join(",", @$array_ref), "\n";;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @perreal I will try to execute the code and let you if works or not.